# Deleting elements out of vector of pointer

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm trying to delete elements in a vector. This works so far, but the I can't free the deleted memory.

The Code I use:

```
vector<TJet*> *tlv_jets;
//...Filling tlv_jets...
for (vector<TJet*>::iterator it = tlv_jets->begin(); it != tlv_jets->end();/*it++*/)
    {
    if (TMath::Abs((*it)->Rapidity()) > ycut)
        {
        cout<< "================" << endl;
        cout<< (*it)->Rapidity() << endl; //Check before deleting
        delete *it;                       //free memory
        cout<< (*it)->Rapidity() << endl; //Check after deleting
        it = tlv_jets->erase(it);         //remove from vector

     }
    else
        ++it;
     }
```

Inside the if is simply the selection of the elements I want to delete.
Both couts return the same value, but I expected a seg fault as I'm trying to access a deleted object. Instead, I run into memory problems as I do not free the memory of the deleted objects correctly. Where does it go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: what memory problem do you run into?

Comment: note if you erase from the vector while iterating, the iterators may be invalidated.

Comment: The memory consumption just rises to infinity and the program failes as it runs out of memory...
Redirecting the iterator to the return value of erase should secure the iterators. At least that's what I've learned from other threads here :-)

Comment: then I guess we need more info to help

Comment: @Rakibul Hasan The iterator will point to the next element after erasing it, so it should be fine as he increments the iterator only if nothing has been deleted

Comment: @RakibulHasan What more information do you need?  His code has undefined behavior.  Running out of memory is a possible result.

Comment: use boost::ptr_vector...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the deleted object is undefined behavior.  There's no
guarantee of a segfault, or anything else.  The `delete *it`
should free up the memory correctly, but following undefined
behavior, all bets are off.  (What does `TJet::Rapidity` do, for
example.  Calling it on a destructed object could result in
corruption of the free space arena, for example.)

Do you still have a problem when you remove the second check?

Also, for what it's worth (but I wouldn't worry about it):

The `delete *it` is formally undefined behavior too, since it
results in an uncopyable object in the vector.  Formally, of
course.  In practice, it's very, very rare for the copy of
a deleted pointer to actually cause any problems, and even if it
does, no implementation of vector will actually copy the deleted
pointer, since it will be overwritten by the erase (without
first being copied).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I agree with you. The problem is, that I get for 10000 out of 10000 cases always the same return value before and after deleting. And this does not look like a undefined behaviour :-( In addition, the memory consumption rises all the time if I call the function described above. 
TJet::Rapidity returns the value of a private variable. So, nothing fancy...

Comment: "And this does not look like a undefined behaviour "  What do you mean?

Comment: sorry for not being precise. For an undefined behavior, I would expect that the two couts would return different values. Only in rare cases the same. Might be, that I'm wrong here...

Comment: Undefined behaviour means anything could happen.  Look at it this way; could you imagine ever raising a bug report with Clang (for example) saying "I know this is undefined behaviour, but surely it shouldn't do {some action}"?

Comment: @ARTcrime Undefined behavior is, well, undefined.  It is very frequent for `delete` to just free the memory, without modifying it, and an access immediately after will still find the same contents.  Throw in something else which allocates between the `delete` and the access, and the behavior will be different.  Modify something through the pointer to the deleted object, and you may end up corrupting the free space arena, resulting in a crash later, in some entirely unrelated code (or possibly resulting in running out of memory).  Anything is possible.

Comment: Okay, I finally got your point. Thanks for the patience and explanation. So, it seems that the hunt for the memory keeps going on as it is probably not in this part of the code :-(

Comment: @ARTcrime _If_ `TJet::Rapidity` is not virtual, and does not modify any data, then it is highly unlikely that this code is the source of the leak.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the TJet::Rapidity content. If there are not any treatments inside this method to TJet members, then won't an error.

Comment: TJet::Rapidity returns a private variable of the TJet class. So, this should cause trouble/undefined behavior when calling on a deleted object.

Comment: Well, may be you don't free some pointers in the TJet destruction and use them in Rapidity?

Comment: I thought that too, but there are no pointer in use inside TJet.

Comment: [here](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/src/TLorentzVector.cxx.html) TJet is derived from that class, adding simply three doubles as private members. And Getter/Setter.

Comment: This answer isn't really correct.  His code contains undefined behavior, regardless of what `TJet::Rapidity` contains.

Answer (score 0):

As a complementary answer, if your compiler supports C++11 you could do this in one line:

```
tlv_jets->erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(*tlv_jets),
                              std::end(  *tlv_jets), 
                              [&] (TJet* e) {
                                if(TMath::Abs(e->Rapidity()) > ycut) {
                                  delete e;
                                  return true;
                                }
                                return false;
                              }), std::end(tlv_jets));
```